# com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.registry.ScalaServiceRegistryClient [] - serviceName=[elastic-search] was not found

Tags: scala, web-services, elasticsearch, cassandra, lagom

I am new in lagom scala. Since I am using elastic-search to store my data as documents. I am also having external cassandra running. When I call an action to store my data in cassandra as well as in elastic-search. since my data data is stored in cassandra successfully but not storing in elastic-search. I have included all the dependencies in Loader as well and lagomUnmanagedServices also for elastic-search.
My Loader class for elastic-search

```
 lazy val elasticSearch= serviceClient.implement[ElasticSearch]


 lazy val indexStore:IndexStore[SearchResult]=wire[ElasticSearchIndexStore]
```

My build.sbt file for elastic-search is

```
lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("elastic-search" -> "http://127.0.0.1:9200")

lagomCassandraEnabled in ThisBuild := false

lagomUnmanagedServices in ThisBuild := Map("cas_native" -> "http://localhost:9042")
```

elastic-search service call

```
override def descriptor: Descriptor ={
  named("elastic-search")
  .withCalls(
    restCall(Method.POST,"/:index/category/:id/_update",updateIndexCategory _)
 .withAutoAcl(true)
```

my trait service method

```
    trait ElasticSearch extends Service
{
  def updateIndexCategory(index:String,id:UUID):ServiceCall[UpdateIndexCategoryData,Done]
}
```

I am externally running elastic-search also. But I dont know why this message showing

```
com.lightbend.lagom.internal.scaladsl.registry.ScalaServiceRegistryClient [] - serviceName=[elastic-search] was not found. Hint: Maybe it was not started?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the error was in lagomUnmanagedServices for cassandra.
I changed it like below

```
lagomCassandraEnabled in ThisBuild := false
lagomCassandraPort in ThisBuild:=9042
```